# iOS Header View height

Tags: ios, swift

I want to support the iPhone X screen in my app, the work is going ok for now but I've hit a obstacle that I do not see a solution for. My UITableView's have a header for each section. I used to calculate the height of the view like this:

```
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var height = CGFloat(0)
    height += Metrics.lineTopHeight
    height += Metrics.padding
    height += headerLabel.sizeThatFits(size).height
    height += Metrics.padding
    height += Metrics.lineBottomHeight

    return CGSize(width: size.width, height: height)
}
```

But for iPhone X I've changed my  horizontal constraints to this:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    constraints.append(headerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor))
    constraints.append(headerLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor))
} else {
    constraints += DXVisual.vfl("H:|[headerLabel]|", views: views)
}
```

So logically I have less room for my headerLabel to be in so I need to change my sizeThatFits function. I thought it should be something like this:

```
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let safeWidth: CGFloat
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        safeWidth = size.width - safeAreaInsets.left - safeAreaInsets.right
    } else {
        safeWidth = size.width
    }

    var height = CGFloat(0)
    height += Metrics.lineTopHeight
    height += Metrics.padding
    height += headerLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: safeWidth, height: size.height)).height
    height += Metrics.padding
    height += Metrics.lineBottomHeight

    return CGSize(width: size.width, height: height)
}
```

But safeAreaInsets is not yet set. How do I do this or am I doing it wrong all together ;)

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please provide screenshot please

Comment: @swift2geek It doesn't really matter how it looks. The real problem is how do I subtract the possible safeAreaInsets from the width since the label will only use that space.

Comment: You need to do the calculation later, after safeAreaInsets have been set. SafeAreaInsets should be set in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: @fishinear I call sizeThatFits in heightForHeaderInSection: for UITableView. I cannot control when it is called.